# Letter Boxed, part 2: this time, solve it

Tags: code-golf, game

This challenge is a sequel to [Letter Boxed Validator](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/183213/letter-boxed-validator).

The New York Times has a daily online game called [Letter Boxed](https://www.nytimes.com/puzzles/letter-boxed) (the link is behind a paywall; the game is also described [here](https://www.polygon.com/2019/2/1/18205854/new-york-times-crossword-letter-boxed-puzzle-game)), presented on a square as follows:

[image: Letter Boxed example from the New York Times]

You are given 4 groups of 3 letters (each group corresponds to one side on the picture); no letter appears twice. The aim of the game is to find words made of those 12 letters (and those letters only) such that:

- Each word is at least 3 letters long;
- Consecutive letters cannot be from the same side;
- The last letter of a word becomes the first letter of the next word;
- All letters are used at least once (letters can be reused).

In this challenge, you are given the letters, and a dictionary. The goal is to output a valid solution, which minimizes the number of words used. If there is no solution, any consistent output is acceptable.

For the input `{{I,C,O}, {M,R,E}, {G,N,S}, {A,P,L}}`, a valid solution is PILGRIMAGE, ENCLOSE. Another valid solution is SOMNOLENCE, EPIGRAM. The following are not valid:

- PILGRIMAGE, ECONOMIES (can't have CO since they are on the same side)
- GRIMACES, SOPRANO (L has not been used)
- PILGRIMAGE, ENCLOSURE (U is not one of the 12 letters)
- ENCLOSE, PILGRIMAGE (last letter of 1st word is not first letter of 2nd word)
- CROPS, SAIL, LEAN, NOPE, ENIGMA (number of words is not minimal)

### Input

Input consists of a dictionary, and of 4 groups of 3 letters. It can be in any suitable format.

### Output

A list of words giving a solution to the challenge. There may be several acceptable solutions: you should output at least one, but may output several if you want.

### Test cases

The test cases use [this dictionary](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/robinryder/misc/master/words.csv). If using a large dictionary is too difficult on [TIO](https://tio.run/), you may use instead the dictionary `{PILGRIMAGE, ENCLOSE, SOMNOLENCE, EPIGRAM, ECONOMIES, GRIMACES, SOPRANO, ENCLOSURE, CROPS, SAIL, LEAN, NOPE, ENIGMA, OVERFLOWS, STACK, QUESTIONABLY, QUARTZ, ZIGZAG, GHERKIN, CODE, GOLF, NO, I, DO, NOT, IN}`, but your code should in principle work on a larger dictionary.

Note that the solution is not necessarily unique; these are possible solutions.

Input=`{{I,C,O}, {M,R,E}, {G,N,S}, {A,P,L}}`.
Solution: PILGRIMAGE, ENCLOSE

Input:`{{OSA}, {FVK}, {WEL}, {CTR}}`.
Solution: OVERFLOWS, STACK.

Input: `{{BCD}, {FGH}, {JKL}, {MNP}}`.
No solution.

Input: `{{AQT}, {LUI}, {BOE}, {NSY}}`.
Solution: QUESTIONABLY

Input: `{{QGN}, {ZUR}, {AHK}, {ITE}}`.
Solution: QUARTZ, ZIGZAG, GHERKIN.

### Scoring:

This [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), lowest score in bytes wins!

Comment: [Sandbox link](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/17744/86301)

Comment: Do I receive the dictionary as input?

Comment: @EmbodimentofIgnorance Yes, dictionary is part of the input. Clarified.

Comment: Such a large dictionary is going to be hard to embed in TIO links -- if it's possible at all. I'd recommend to provide a much smaller dictionary including all words used in the solutions and just a couple of other useless ones.

Comment: @Arnauld OK, I've added a small dictionary which should be enough for all test cases.

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 38 bytes

```
iⱮⱮL>2ƊƇẠƇ’:3IẠƲƇŒPU=ḢɗƝẠ$ƇFQL=ʋƇ12ịḷḢ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY0xSwMxFMf3@xTlcKyD7WZpIU1zabxcXi65a@ntDpZuTm7V5cBuLiJYEJcuIiiCxYJLMaDf4u6LnEkEIcn/938v7//mp4vFRdOc1S/P9vBBx1ybsvp4MGW9vDvuMoevpvy6kXm/2j5@35q1LR2YMkp5/2dlyqNOtVtV23fbbPabeX352W4F5915vVy3e/XyvnU4aFnu7TdBtXvbb@qrp1nTMAyJIlRoJHkAGkWTeEo4zlQwxKOIjk9inggZoDTjORsCEXoWpFQUuULjmGWkCSXjVLEEURK2QyIwB@1IQyKAW@/LklGFEkcYBCSMaMt@DHvUIBUS8J@QKzeGFUjfRYxb4QQJKwLk3ypGE2QBJkRFHKb@Z4ZwbDXNic4YCDTkM2@RygoLBaMFom73mKiYuTgMIxdHgUc@3D7M3hF4lzkrwl8)

A dyadic link taking the flattened letters as left argument and the dictionary as right. Returns a list of strings of one of the shortest solutions, or a zero if there is no solution.

Full explanation to follow once it’s a bit better golfed.